# About Fermat's last Theorem?beal etc

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I could not get the point why people are so crazy about FLT?, I have seen that there is no much difference in Beal conjecture as well as FLT. Why people will pose such conjecture and announce prize money, when there is no application/use in Math/science. If there is any use of applicability of this theorem in reality, where we can apply? what are the uses in real life? If you know, please let me know. Clearly, I want to lean the applicability of the FLT or beal in real life? If there, let me know as well as other members.

Thanks in advance
-Richard Sieman

Comment: "Sometimes the journey is more important than the destination."

Comment: Well for as for the popularity from a non-mathematical viewpoint... FLT is a simple problem that most can understand, with an arguably cool backstory, with an amazing proof. Beal's conjecture from what I looked up, is not proven, I would argue doesn't have as cool a backstory, and not quite as trivial in terms of describing the problem to a non-mathematician (although don't get me wrong, it isn't like it is impossible to understand). I saw a documentary on FLT in high school as an inspiration. If you are looking for more mathematical reason, someone else should probably answer.

Comment: @anon! Still I am looking more.

Comment: When first conjectured, the problem was so amazingly simply yet so hard to prove at the same time. I guess that was what made it popular.

Comment: It'd be interesting to know what "real life" and like what "applications to it" mean to you, @RichardSieman .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Why people will pose such conjecture and announce prize money, when there is no application or use in Math/science.*

To answer a question with a question: Why do people offer up to millions of dollars for guessing six numbers out of $49$, or winning a poker tournament, when that has even *less* applicability in math, life, and science ? :-)